# Open WebStorm in Presentation Mode

Tags: view, settings, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, presentation

Is it possible to open `WebStorm` in Presentation Mode from the very launch of the ide?

I mean before closing the ide, I am using a Presentation Mode, but once ide is closed and reopened the Presentation Mode is not preserved and I have to enable it manually again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**There is currently no way to launch WebStorm directly in presentation mode.**

You could [make a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WEB) to JetBrains and hope for the best.

Meanwhile, you can easily define a key binding to toggle presentation mode.

[image]